# jQuery: Disable button 10min after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable button 10 minutes after it was clicked. I am using this code and it is working if there is no delay() added. But with delay it is not working.

```
<script>
$(".selected-button").delay(600000).attr({
    disabled: true,
    title: "You have already chosen the best answer and now you can not change it!"
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can use setTimeout

Comment: `.delay()` only works on effects, like animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this using `setTimeout` instead:

```
$(".selected-button").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr("disabled", true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.removeAttr("disabled");      
    }, 600000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable button 10 minutes after click:

```
$(".selected-button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        done: function (data) {
            if (data.status === 'OK') {
                var that = $(this);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    that.prop("disabled", true);
                }, 10*60*1000);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9xEM/) example for 5s.

Comment: @JatinSoni the button will be disabled after 10min of click. When do you want it fired?

Comment: @JatinSoni Edited if you want your button disabled only after a **ajax** successful response. I just realized that because I've seen your comment in Satpal answer. Please, **update your question** to let us know clearly of this info!! (title should be "Disable after ajax call")